# How would I get past this assertion test in Python for trying to find the sum of all the number of views listed in a Dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

How would I get past this assertion test in Python for trying to find the sum of all the number of views? Below is the dictionary I am given, and then below that is assertion test I am trying to pass. I have to create a function that returns something that passes the assertion.

```
video_reviews = [
    {
        "name": "Cats doing nothing",
        "number_of_views": 450743,
        "reviews": [
            {"name": "Jeb", "review": 5},
            {"name": "Samantha", "review": 2},
            {"name": "Crystal", "review": 3},
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "All Fail",
        "number_of_views": 1239734,
        "reviews": [
            {"name": "Crystal", "review": 5},
            {"name": "Frank", "review": 3},
            {"name": "Jeb", "review": 3},
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Runaway Nintendo",
        "number_of_views": 48343,
        "reviews": [
            {"name": "Samantha", "review": 4},
            {"name": "Bill", "review": 3},
            {"name": "Sarah", "review": 4},
        ]
    },
]
```

```
assert total_by_video(video_reviews, "Runaway Nintendo") == 48343
assert total_by_video(video_reviews, "All Fail") == 1239734
assert total_by_video(video_reviews, "Critters") == 0
```

Comment: can you please show us the code you've tried so far?

Comment: Your real question is "How can I write a function called `total_by_video` that returns the number of views for a given name?"  It has nothing to do with assertions.  All the assertions are doing it checking the output of the function you need to write.

Comment: Looks like Homework

Answer (score 0):

`video_reviews` is a list of dictionaries. For a single dictionary `d` you can get the number of views like this: `number_of_views=d["number_of_views"]`
With that knowledge you can use either a for-loop or list-comprehension to create a list that contains only the numbers.

`number_of_views_list = [450743, 1239734, 48343]`

Now all you have to do is sum up this list. This can be done by a for-loop as well, or you could make use of the `sum` function.

Your function would probably look somewhat like this:

```py
def sum_of_views(reviews):
    # TODO create number_of_views_list
    # TODO sum up number_if_views_list
    return result
```